# Can I build a jooq query into an offset?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to build something like the following query using the jooq api.

```
select x.*
from x
offset greatest(0, (select count(*) - 1 from x));
```

by

```
select(x.fields()).from(x)
  .offset(param(greatest(val(0), select(count().sub(1)).from(x).field(0, Integer.class))))
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using the `offset(Param<Integer>)` method incorrectly. It seems to be rendering `null` for the offset. Is building up offsets like this something that jooq can do? (It seems like the `offset` method is a bit restricted in what it can do, compared to the rest of the jooq api.)

(I know this query without context seems inefficient, but it's actually what I want to be doing.)

Thanks!

Comment: The question is: Can you do it in your database? (what is your database?)

Comment: Yep. Can do it in postgres. I'm actually doing it using a CTE, but turns out that it's not limited to CTEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I don't think any database allows you to put a non-constant expression in their `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses</strike> (it *is* possible in PostgreSQL, see dsmith's comments). In any case, jOOQ doesn't allow you to do it. You must provide either a constant `int` value, or a bind variable (a `Param`).

But you don't really need that feature in your case anyway. Your hypothetical syntax ...

```sql
select x.*
from x
offset greatest(0, (select count(*) - 1 from x));
```

Is equivalent to this:

```sql
select x.*
from x
order by <implicit ordering> desc
limit 1;
```

After all, your query seems to be looking for the *last* row (by some implicit ordering), so why not just make that explicit?

Comment: Mentioned above, but this is legal postgres syntax. By the time I get the table, the original ordering field isn't present (so I can't reverse the ordering). Will have to rework my query at a higher level to get my desired results out.

Anyways, just confirming that jooq doesn't allow query building like this. Thanks.

Comment: @dsmith: Oh, thanks for the pointer. I wasn't aware of this. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5695. Of course, you *could* work around jOOQ's limitation by intercepting the generated SQL string and patching your own `OFFSET` expression in it. E.g. using an `ExecuteListener`